# Windows Service not stopping in Windows Server 2012 but easily on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-7, windows-server-2012

I have a below script which is attached to a windows service on stop command:-

```
wmic service where name='%NS_SERVICE_NAME%' get ProcessId | more +1 > tmp.txt
set /p NS_PID=<tmp.txt
del tmp.txt
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where "(ParentProcessId=%NS_PID%)" get ProcessId ^| more +1') do (
    for /f %%a in ('wmic process where "(ParentProcessId=%%i)" get ProcessId ^| more +1') do (
        echo %%a|findstr "^[-][1-9][0-9]*$ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ^0$">nul && TASKKILL /F /PID %%a || rem
        IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 do (
           exit
        )
    )
)
```

which works fine on Windows 7 and service stops quickly in 1-2 seconds, but in case of Windows Server 2012 the service does not stop and keeps in stopping state unless the process related to it is ended.

The error which I get in logs is as below:- "No Instance(s) Available."

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Have you considered asking the service to shutdown itself rather than killing the process? The latter could well leave the service's data in a corrupt state. Try `sc stop servicename` and give it time to stop (if performing a complex operation completion will not be immediate).

Comment: @Richard: I left the service to stop on itself for almost an hour, but still it was in stopping state, so I had to kill the process. This issue is occuring with windows 2012 server, whereas in case of windows 7, its working like charm

Comment: So diagnose the problem: what is the service doing? What's in the event log? What's in the service's own logging? (Showing you can kill the processes doesn't help work out why you might feel the need to kill it.)

Comment: nothing comes in event viewer application logs, but in system logs of event viewer we get that "The Openfire_ns service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this x time(s)."

Comment: Did you run `openfire-service /stop` as [documented](http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html#windows)?

Comment: it is run through a batch file as windows service, I am not aware if it uses the documented way to start or stop the service.

Comment: Would it hurt terribly if you checked?

Comment: I checked through the code and could not find anything else apart from the code mentioned in the question which is used to stop the service.

Comment: Then please try the documented way.